# What is the best way to print out the value of an HTML element while testing/developing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is `alert`, and `console.log` are the only 2 ways to print out the value base on ID if an element ? I'm looking for a better alternative. Any suggestion/recommendation on that ?

Comment: Logging is generally done using the `console`. Is there something specific about your testing that would necessitate something more?

Comment: No. I was just seeking to other developers out there, maybe they have some other better option for printing out a value.

Comment: console.log is usually the most efficient for developers.  Everything else is harder to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say `alert` and `console.log` are the most common. `console.log` is typically the go-to method developers use to log things. If you're wanting something else that doesn't require you to have the console open, you could always create a function that inserts your message into an element on your page.

```html
<div id="log-output"></div>
```

```js
function logger (message) {
    var logOutput = document.getElementById('log-output');

    logOutput.innerHTML = message;
}

function someOtherFunction () {
    logger('log this!');
}

someOtherFunction();
```

But, really, I'd suggest just using `console.log` :)

Comment: Precisely !!  I will keep that in mind. Thanks @Trevan Hetzel

Answer (score 1):

You should use `console.log`. The `alert` is useful but if you forget to remove it from your production code it could cause you some issues (like show to your users some sensitive data).

Note that you could group the messages you log using `console.error`, `console.warn` or `console.log`.

Answer (score 1):

funny.. nobody mentioned **console.dir** method.

the main difference between dir an log is that the log prints the values while dir breaking the output to it's basic components thus creating a tree of hierarchy (way better when dealing with complex types, JSON results etc)

here is a **live sample** which demonstrate the difference:  http://jsfiddle.net/ymzrocks/sz3tjthf

```
var obj =
{
    a: 'hello',
    b: [10, 20, 30, 40],
    c: 
    {
        x: new Date(),
        y: 
        {
            more: '...'   
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj);
console.dir(obj)
```

Comment: Wow. good to know that. It's totally worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Another method not mentioned is to use the developer tools in the different browsers (Usually F12 to bring them up). There you can inspect the different elements and insert breakpoints in your JS files without any changes to your code. I think it's more readable when looking at HTML elements than using alert or console.log.

Comment: Again, each tip, you guy post here is really helpful ! I will try that.